# How to escape character in power automate with dynamic data from query

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

I am trying to filter rows with: name eq 'nameFromQueryData'
One name is breaking the filter: Paul O'Meefe

Its due to the filter needing to escape the ' inside the name. Its reading it as: name eq 'Paul O' (end string) Meffe' (start string) = error

Since this is dynamic data, I cant just use the escape character O/'.

So how would one go about escaping it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using fetchxml instead - it's a lot more adaptable and forgiving instead of an odata query in Power Automate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlDS7.png)